# ReactJS map function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neo4j, map-function

After I click the submit button a query goes to a Neo4j DB and the response is sent back.  Also, when the button is click another function is sending that data to the Graph function `{this.state.submit && this.displayElements()}`.  Once in the Graph function I trying to render a graph but React is saying map is undefined. However, a console log of props from inside Graph shows: `{data:{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050, object: Array(1), Second: Array(1), __typename: "action", …}`. I have tried different combination before map but nothing seems to work (this.props.nodes, this.state.action, etc).

Display Function (Sending data via props as nodes)

```
displayElements = () => {
        const {data:{loading, error, action}} = this.props;
        console.log(this.props);
        if(loading) {
            return <option disabled>Loading...</option>;
          }else if (error){
            return<p>Error!</p>;
          }
          return (

     <Graph nodes={this.data}/>  <--Sending data to Graph via props as nodes
            );
          }
```

Graph Function

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {nodes: this.props};
    console.log(this.props + "graph")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.force = d3.forceSimulation(this.state.nodes)
      .force("charge",
        d3.forceManyBody()
          .strength(this.props.forceStrength)
      )
      .force("x", d3.forceX(this.props.width / 2))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(this.props.height / 2));

    this.force.on('tick', () => this.setState({nodes: this.state.nodes}));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.force.stop();
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>
        {this.state.nodes.action.map((node, index) =>(
            <circle r={node.r} cx={node.x} cy={node.y} fill="red" key={index}/>
        ))}
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: Can you try like that for a test: `(this.state.nodes.action || [] ).map`?

Comment: No errors but the screen is Blank.

Comment: As I asked in the given answer's comments, which data do you want to map here?  `action` is a string.

Comment: I would like to map the action object. Not sure what you mean by I would set data sate in a different way...

Comment: You are getting the data as props, why don't you use it directly? This is what I meant. But, let's focus the actual problem here. `data` is an object here right. `action` is a string in this object. Am I seeing wrong?

Comment: No, action is also an object in action.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178689/discussion-between-devserkan-and-n6dyn).

Answer (score 1):

map is for an array, but your passing objects `{data:{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050, object: Array(1), Second: Array(1), __typename: "action", …}`

A solution can be `Object.keys(this.state.nodes.action).map(()=>{...}`

```
{Object.keys(this.state.nodes.action).map((node, index) =>(
     <circle r={node.r} cx={node.x} cy={node.y} fill="red" key={index}/>
))}
```

Comment: @Schaleb I got TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: in your `render(){...}` can you put this inside `console.log('nodes received : ',this.state.nodes.action)`. To see if you actually get data when render begins.

Comment: Oh, I missed the data shape. `this.state.nodes.action` is a string here. Am I missing something? Which data do you want to map in this object? Also, I would set data state in a different way than assigning it to my props.

Comment: I would like to map the action object. Not sure what you mean by `I would set data sate in a different way...`.

Comment: @N6DYN What did you get when you tried console.log?

Comment: @SGhaleb I got the following error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: No, you were meant to get a result first when doing `console.log('nodes received : ', this.state.nodes.action)` before `return(...)`

Comment: `nodes received :  undefined`

Comment: That's the problem, you are not getting your results when rendering. `componentDidMount ()` happens after `render(){...}` , so you will need to get data first, then render

Comment: `node: this.props` in the state. Something going on so weird here. Don't use it like that. Let's go to chat.